# Why a separate function works with Must property rather than write the entire expression in it? (FluentValidation)

Tags: c#, linq, fluentvalidation

I am a newbie with Linq and fluent validation and I want to know.. Why with the method 1 I get an error but with the method 2 it works without any issue?.

## This way doesn't work!! throws a null reference exception.

```
 RuleFor(x => x)
        .Must(ledger => !_companyDbContext.GeneralLedger.Any(x =>
            x.Deleted == false
            && !(x.Id == ledger.Id)
            && x.AccountNumber == ledger.AccountNumber
            &&  x.LedgerAccount == ledger.LedgerAccount
            && x.AccountType == ledger.AccountType 
            &&  x.Description == ledger.Description
            )).WithMessage(ValidatorResources.Unique_Message);
```

## This way works even if all the properties of the object are null.

```
    RuleFor(x => x)
        .Must(testDuplicateRecords)
        .WithMessage("duplicated record");

public bool testDuplicateRecords( GeneralLedger ledger)
{
    Expression<Func<GeneralLedger, bool>> predicate = (x) => x.Deleted == false && !(x.Id == ledger.Id)
        && x.AccountNumber == ledger.AccountNumber
        && x.LedgerAccount == ledger.LedgerAccount
        && x.AccountType == ledger.AccountType
        && x.Description == ledger.Description;


    return !_companyDbContext.GeneralLedger.Any(predicate.Compile());

}
```

Comment: I don't call this fluent validation by the way (regardless of framework used)

Comment: Don't say `x.Deleted == false` say `!x.Deleted`. Don't say `!(x.Id == ledger.Id)` say `x.Id != ledger.Id`.

Comment: What LINQ provider?

Comment: Just a detail : are you sure that the error isn't raised by `ValidatorResources.Unique_Message` ? Cause it's not used in your second sample.

Comment: -RaphaëlAlthaus. I am pretty sure that is not raised by ValidatorResources because I used in other validators.



-NetMage thank you I will take it as a consideration about the syntax. In regards about what linq provider is linq to sql.

-M.kazemAkhgary call it whatever you want is not my business. I have to point the stuff that I am using if I could do it in a better way please say it thank you..